# How can I train on video data using Keras? "transfer learning"

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I want to train my model on video data for gesture recognition, proposed using [LSTM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_short-term_memory)'s and TimeDistributed layers. Would this be ideal way to tackle my problem?

```
# Convolution
pool_size = 4

# LSTM
lstm_output_size = 1

print('Build model...')

model = Sequential()

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(62), input_shape=(img_width, img_height,3)))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size))

# model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(256, return_sequences=True))
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(256, return_sequences=True))
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(256, return_sequences=True))
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(lstm_output_size))
model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
print('Train...')
model.summary()
# Run epochs of sampling data then training
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For temporal sequence data LSTM networks are generally the right choice. If you want to analyze video then a combination with 2d convolutions sounds reasonable to me. However, you have to apply TimeDistributed on all layers which dont expect sequence data. In your example that means all laysers expect LSTM.

```
# Convolution
pool_size = 4

# LSTM
lstm_output_size = 1

print('Build model...')

model = Sequential()

model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(62), input_shape=(img_width, img_height,3)))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (3, 3))))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Conv2D(32, (3, 3))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=pool_size)))

# model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(256, return_sequences=True))
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(256, return_sequences=True))
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(256, return_sequences=True))
model.add(CuDNNLSTM(lstm_output_size))
model.add(Dense(units = 1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
print('Train...')
model.summary()
# run epochs of sampling data then training
```

The last Dense Layer can stay this way because the final lstm doesnt output a sequence.